# Are there tests on parameter stability for time series rolling OLS?

Tags: statistical-significance, change-point

I have an OLS model implemented in a rolling window scheme. The estimated params $\beta$ do change for each window, and the entire intention is to capture any structural change, but they should not be too "jumpy" either.

I looked into tests such as MOSUM, and more generalized Chow tests, but on those metrics, the scenarios where my model is acceptable to me would not pass the tests by far.

I am quite tempted to treat the "mean" / "std" of my parameters as a "t-statistic" and use that as a test for stability. I would appreciate some theoretical direction or suggestion into how sensible my intuition here is.